# What does invalid initialization of reference mean?

Tags: c++, reference, compiler-errors, initialization

My code is like this

`std::string & Product::getDescription() const { 
    return &description; 
}`

I've tried it all different ways with description and *description and nothing works, but when I take off the reference part of the return type it works fine. The thing is though that we're supposed to use &. I'm really confused as to why nothing works. Also earlier in the project there was the code:

`void Product::setDescription(const std::string &newUnits) const { 
    units = newUnits; 
}`

With units being declared as a global public variable. The exact error it gives me is:

> error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::string& {aka std::basic_string&}’ from expression of type ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string}’

Comment: What type is `description`?

Comment: Are you sure that's the right error message?

Comment: can you provide the full declaration of `Product`?

Comment: You declare returning a reference, but you are returning a pointer (`&description` is an address)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you initialize reference you don't use `&` operator on variable:

```
int i = 0;
int& j = i;  // now j is reference for i
```

similarly in the function, return variable without `&`:

```
std::string& Product::getDescription() const {
    return description;
} // equivalent for std::string& returned = description;
```

In addition you are allowed to return only const reference from const function. So this should be:

```
const std::string& Product::getDescription() const {
    return description;
}
```

or

```
std::string& Product::getDescription() {
    return description;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured out what I did about ten minutes after I posted this, but the explanation is always appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When returning a reference you don't use the `address-of` operator:

```
class Product
{
   std::string description;
   const std::string& get_description() const { return description; }
   void set_description(const std::string& desc) { description = desc; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a `const` member function, meaning that the object that it's called on (and its members) are `const` within the function. You can't return a non-const reference to a member.

You can return a `const` reference from a `const` function:

```
const std::string & Product::getDescription() const;
```

and a non-const reference from a non-const function

```
std::string & Product::getDescription();
```

Assuming `description` has type `std::string`, you would return the reference with just `return description;`, with no `&`.

The `set` function can't be `const`, since it modifies the object.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `Product::getDescription() const` should return a reference to a const object, because the method is const. What is more, `&description` is pointer to the string, because in that context `&` is the *address-of* operator. You do not initialize a reference from a pointer. Use the following:

```
const std::string & Product::getDescription() const { return description; }
```